# Why is this program giving unexpected output?

Tags: c, increment

```
int main()
{
    int x = 3, z ;
    z = x / + + x ;
    printf ("x = %dz = %d", x , z );
    return 0;
}
```

I thought the output will be `x=4 z=0` or `x=4 z=1`. But I'm getting `x=3 z=1`.

Comment: You might want to read [this question and its accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thanks for the link, but I think the question has some rather basic syntactic mistake.

Comment: @nishant Yes, but when that's fixed it's still undefined behavior as described in my link.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Right, but after giving two answer possibilities, I think user itself is expecting a UB. :-)

Comment: @nishant good logic bhai

Answer (score 3):

Try removing spaces between `++` (increment operator). Use `++x` or `++ x`. Compiler may be interpreting it as `+(+x)`, i.e. `unary +` operator.

Comment: Ironically, that means in its current form the behaviour is perfectly defined.

Comment: @Medinoc : Right, may be here it is, but I think it may happen that on seeing a string of `/ + +` some compiler report Compile Error.

Comment: @nishant Why would "some compilers report Compile Error"? That's a perfectly valid sequence of operators.

Comment: @H2CO3 : I didn't tried running it, but `/ + +` lacks operands between the two `+`. I thought some compiler may interpret it this way and report error. Is it so that it will always be interpreted as `+(+x)`?

Comment: @nishant It's absolutely unambiguous. One `/` operator then two unary `+`. Any compiler rejecting it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

remove spaces in between two pluses

```
z = x / ++ x ;  //will gives z value as 1 always
```

//except  when x=-1 (Floating point exception )

this Might have Undefined Behaviour because Lack of sequence point.

rather than above if you could try like this.

```
int x = 3, z=3;
printf ("x = %dz = %d", x , z );

z/=(++x); // z/=++x; is also same.  
printf ("x = %dz = %d", x , z );
```